# Magento-2 exception printing is disabled by default

Tags: magento2, error, exception

I was having an error on my webpage `exception printing is disabled by default`
so I looked for solution and I found an answer to change the `local.xml.sample.` into `local.xml` after doing this I have a new error called `Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "40" already exists.`

Can somebody tell me what to do here because i can't found `magento/catalog/model/category/intercepter` anywhere?

Comment: Paste the custom code you added the led to this result.

Comment: i was adding new categories and when i refreshed the website it showed me the error of exception is disabled by default. so i went to pub/errors/ and changed the name of local.xml.sample to local.xml

Comment: and after that it showed me that error Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor) with the same ID "40" already exists. on website.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same situation. Try delete category, wich had ID - 40, and delete some rules from

> Admin>>Marketing>>Url Rewrites

where category id is 40.

Comment: i solved the issue y changing the default root category..